# How to create a column that is the result of a division of two existing columns?

Tags: powerbi

I have the following table in my `PowerBI` dashboard

[image]

In order to get `Distinct` count of patients per age range I added the `patient` field and set it to do `Count (Distinct)`

[image]

Now I need a third column that is the result of the division of the `budgetfee` column and the `Count of patient`.

**How would I calculate that third column?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a measure using the `DIVIDE` function:

```
MyMeasure = 
DIVIDE ( 
    SUM ( MyTable[budgetfree] ),
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( MyTable[patient] ),
    BLANK()
)
```

Comment: Yep, the columns already there use ***implicit measures*** and this calculated their quotient.

Comment: Can I use this column after for other math operations, for example Query1[MyMesasure] ?

Comment: You can refer to measures in other measures, yes

Comment: just last question why do you use Blank at the end?

Comment: The final argument of the `DIVIDE` function determines what is returned in the error case (e.g. divide by zero)

Comment: No hard feelings, but I found the following quite funny@Olly: half an hour prior VAAA asking what the Blank does at the end, I proposed an edit where I added an explanation of the (simple) formula. You [rejected my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21529750) because `This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.` 
Right...